# Unzip a .zip file to a specific directory using jar command

Tags: jar, zip, unzip

How to unzip a .zip file to a specific directory using jar command in command prompt?

Eg. I have a zip file as stackover.zip. Now I want to extract the files inside the zip file using jar command. The files should be extracted to main1\overflow.

I tried executing `jar stackover.zip -C main1\overflow`

Comment: Why not using the zip/unzip command, if it is a zip file?

Comment: @Jens, it is possible that the OP is on a Windows environment where he does not have the `zip` utility

Comment: @AnuShibinJosephRaj In that case, the obvious solution is to install it, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

The `jar` utility does not have the provision to specify a target directory.

Alternatively, you can `cd` into the folder where you want to extract the files and then execute the `jar` command from there. For example:

```
cd ./main1/overflow
jar xf ../../stackover.zip
```

Comment: But this doesn't solve my issue. I don't want to use *cd* command. Is there any alternative way to do this?

Comment: I am afraid not. As mentioned, the `jar` command does not provide an API to specify the target directory. You will have to use other tools that allow you to specify a target directory.

Comment: I smell a repeating pattern here. "I don't want to use the correct tool for the job." May I ask why?